# Close an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

How to close and activity button click ?

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ******I WANT THE CODE HERE ???? **********

    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply call `finish();` in button's **onClick**

Answer (score 2):

Just add `finish();` to your listener.

Comment: Why you answer this question as you know that @Waqas already answer this simple question ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval: offten I see a question with no answer (yet). I start creating an answer and press the submit-button. In the mean time other have also answered (which i haven-t noticed). If you look at the answer-timestamp they are all quite close together. May be somthing similar has happend here..

Comment: @Chirag Raval i would rather know why is someone asking this question here , and dont utfg.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ******I WANT THE CODE HERE ???? **********
           YourActivity.this.finish(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Why you answer this question as you know that @Waqas already answer this simple question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      finish();
   }
});
```

Comment: Why you answer this question as you know that @Waqas already answer this simple question before 4 mins ago?

Comment: @ChiragRaval So what..?? We have a rights to answer any question whether it is answered or not...